# "User was removed" multiple reputation decrement from one upvote (and upvote is still on post)

Tags: support, reputation

I received an upvote on an old post early this morning. I log back in this evening and see my rep down 30 points. Upon examining the reputation log I see, in triplicate, a "User removed" -10:

[image: multiple downvotes]

Another curious thing is that the actual vote count on the post in question did not change at all. It was +4 after getting the single upvote this morning and now it remains at +4.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those statements don't necessarily have to apply to a post that *recently* got an upvote. The only thing you can conclude from those events is that three users were deleted and each of the users caused you to gain 10 reputation *somewhere in the past*. There's no way of knowing *which* posts caused the gain, or even how many posts were involved. They may have all been the same post, they may have been three (or more) random posts scattered across your history.

Comment: So the post/answer doesn't loose the upvote and be indicated as such in the rep log?

Comment: No, all the events that have occurred from that user to you are grouped together into one removal event. In fact, the score of the posts involved won't update until someone further votes on the post or expands the vote count, but that is a minor cosmetic glitch. The "User was removed" event in your history is simply an indication of why you lost a certain amount of reputation.

Answer (score 4):

That's just coincidental placement. Those three removed upvotes are probably for one or more of your other answers.

I removed five sock puppets of a user at exactly that time, so that's probably what the source for those removed votes were. Sorry about that, but they weren't real accounts to begin with.